# Power BI Relationship established, but # values are the same when leveraging

Tags: powerbi, relationship

[image]

I have created a relationship between multiple data sources and am trying to leverage information across them. I ideally want to show the cost associated with different banking transactions by company. These would come from the deals table and the cost table - the two at either end of the relationship.[image]

[image]

I tried deleting blanks, removing excess values etc. I am hoping the relationship can be fixed.

Comment: Filters flow in the direction of the little arrows.  So Payments doesn't filter Cost.

Comment: Is there any way too fix this so that I can? Related Table or some other function. I also tried making the arrows flow in both directions, but to no avail.

Comment: What table does "Count of Name" come from?

Comment: Count of name is just a measure gives the total of all different names of companies in the Deals table

Comment: If you put Deals in a separate table and add filter on Company Name, does it filter down?

Comment: Yes, I normally would just add the field a second time to the same visual - a table in this case, but would select count instead of don't summarize.

Comment: So it appears to be filtering.  Can you produce a minimal repro with hand-entered data?

Comment: I have saved a new picture onto the post. Essentially I would like to be able to see Cost Per company coming from Deals. So I link deals to entity info (think of this as a key, contains client info) through company name, entity info to payments using company name, payments is linked to cost using a concatenation code to represent different wire possibilities and cost has the cost within it. I can't link deals to payments directly because that would be a many to many, multiple companies have multiple deals and payments

Comment: I also cannot use the companies from payments, because i want to list other info from the deals column like fees charged and revenue to compare

Answer (score 0):

ENTITY_INFO filters PAYMENTS but not Cost.

To calculate the total cost of all payments for a company, add a measure like

```
TotalPaymentCost = sumx(PAYMENTS,RELATED(Cost[Cost]))
```

.  Most commonly this measure would be added to the PAYMENTS table, but it doesn't actually matter what table you put measures on.